# Circular Queue error, display option acting as remove option. [Java OOP]

Tags: java, oop, queue

So I have this assignment which is meant to simulate passengers waiting at a boarding gate and we need to create a menu with different options. For it we have to have two classes and a main program and the entire thing is supposed to be based on a circular queue.

While attempting to do the circular queue, I stumbled upon the problem mentioned in the title. When I add items to the queue, once I attempt to display them with the option from the menu, the queue pops the first item, which is not meant to do unless the option delete from the menu is called. Furthermore, if I call the delete and view options, the queue deletes two items. To summarize:

- I have no idea why my view option acts as a delete option

Any suggestions as to how to resolve this are appreciated because I've been trying for hours on end, I re-wrote the passenger queue class a few times in different ways, yet still the same and currently I have no idea how to resolve it.

The program is as it follows:

Main:

```
public class Airport {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PassengerQueue queue1= new PassengerQueue();
        Passenger[]  ArrayOfPassenger = new Passenger[20];
        Scanner input= new Scanner (System.in);
       String optionMenu;
       for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
      ArrayOfPassenger[i]= new Passenger();
    char letter;
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter display option [A-add passenger, V- view passenger queue, D- delete passenger from queue, S- store passengerQueue data into file, L- load passengerQueue data from file] or 'X' to stop: ");
            optionMenu = input.next();
            letter = optionMenu.charAt(0);
            switch (letter) {
                case 'A':
                    queue1.AddPassenger();
                    break;
                case 'V':
                    queue1.display();
                case 'D':
                   queue1.removePassenger();
                    break;
                case 'S':

                    break;
                case 'L':

                    break;


            }

        } while (letter != 'X');

    }
}
```

Passenger class:

```
   public class Passenger {
        private String firstName;
        private String surname;
        private int secondsInQueue;
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        /**
         *
         * @return
         */
        public String getname(){
            return firstName= " "+surname;
        }

        public void setName (String fName, String sName){
        firstName=fName;
        surname=sName;
        }
        public Passenger (){
        firstName= "";
        surname="";
        }
        public String toString() {
        return firstName + " " + surname;
    }
```

And PassengerQueue class, which is having the issue:

```
 public class PassengerQueue {
    Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
    private Passenger[] qArray =new Passenger [20];
    private int first = 0;
    private int last = 0;
    private int maxStayInQueue;
    static final int MAX_QUEUE_SIZE = 20;
    public PassengerQueue() {
    for (int i = 0;i < 20; i++)
        qArray[i]= new Passenger();
}


public void AddPassenger() {

    System.out.println("Enter passenger's First Name:");
    String FirstName = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter passenger's surname:");
    String Surname= input.next();
    qArray[last].setName(FirstName, Surname);
    last++;
    if(last == qArray.length+1){
        last = 0;
    }
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return first == 0;
}

public boolean isFull() {
    return last == 19;
}
public void removePassenger(){
Passenger x;
x= qArray[first];
qArray[first].setName("","");
first=first+1;
if(first==qArray.length+1)
    first=0;
}
    public void display() {
    System.out.println("The queue: ");
    for(int i = first; i < last; i++)
        System.out.println(qArray[i]);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You miss the **break;** statement after 
**queue1.display();** in class **Airport** main method.
So the next case'D' executed.

Comment: I would help to show the corrected code with the summary you provided.

Comment: Thank you very much! I totally missed that, oh my God, I am really embarrassed right about now. Again, thank you very much.